# Get the 2nd Friday of a month with MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get the `nth` Friday of a month with momentjs

where `n` is in the range `[1,4]`

So if a user supplies n as 2. Then I need to get the date for the second Friday of the month.

Here is what I tried with no sucess

```
let startingFrom = new Date("StartDateStringGoesHere");
let n=2;
let nthFriday = moment(startDate).isoWeekday(n); //I can't figure out how to resolve it here
```

Any ideas will be truly appreciated.

Comment: `isoWeekday(n)` will get you the n'th day of the week i.e. An n of 2 results in Tuesday. Probably not the function you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic function, no library needed

```js
function nthWeekdayOfMonth(year, month, nth, dow) {
    const d = new Date(year, month - 1, 7 * (nth - 1) + 1);
    const w = d.getDay();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + (7 + dow - w) % 7);
    return d;
}
// second(2) friday(5)
for (let month = 1; month < 13; month++) {
    console.log(nthWeekdayOfMonth(2022, month, 2, 5).toString());
}

// third(3) sunday(0)
for (let month = 1; month < 13; month++) {
    console.log(nthWeekdayOfMonth(2022, month, 3, 0).toString());
}
```

Comment: Wow @Bravo. Nice one!! However can you explain what `dow` is?

Comment: oh, right @user15155716 ... dow === day of week ... 0 is sunday, 1 is monday .... 5 is friday and 6 is saturday

Comment: @user15155716 I've added comments to explain - also, the month is January == 1, unlike javascript `Date`s - where January is 0 - I like to make my functions user friendly :p

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example function to do this in m

```
// Using moment get all Fridays in a month
const searchDate = moment()

function getNthDay(n, day, startDate){
    let daysArray = []
    for (let i = 0; i <= startDate.daysInMonth(); i++) {
        const currentDay = moment().startOf("month").add(i, "days");
        if (currentDay.format('dddd') === day) {
            daysArray.push(currentDay);
        }
    }
    
    return daysArray[n];
}

const nDay = getNthDay(1, 'Friday', searchDate);

console.log(nDay)
```